how to fix jagged sharp edges in sculpting?
Hi i have a scanned mesh with sharp edges but blender's "draw sharp" and "pinch" brushes are giving me jagged edges while trying to sharpening those edges is there any ways i can overcome that ?
lets say i want to fix this issue on a scanned mesh with sculpting

but every time i try i end up like this

and these jagged edges are alot, smoothing alone doesn't work cause i loose the whole sharp detail in there, and if i want to create the sharpness myself the whole sharp edge that i created will become jagged too .
what i want is a way to smooth theses details without loosing the sharp detail, slide relax doesn't work , fill brush doesn't work, idk how to fix this .

To me, that seems like the kind of thing to fix during retopology.

@AllenSimpson yep ! but i don't have time for retopology, i don't know how but my coworker does it much more faster via geomagic wrap software
